# Apps Script binds differently depending on input source

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code, which is acting as a custom function for a Google Spreadsheet:

```
// counts the instances of elem in an array called list
function countInstances(elem, list) {
  var p = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] == elem) p++;
  }
  return p
}

function J(E) {
  //var E =   ["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c"];
  var elems = E.getUnique();
  var b;

 return countInstances(elems[0], E);
}
```

It seems straight-forward, but something strange is happening:

- When I uncomment "var E" in the code, b returns what I would expect it to return: 4 for a, 4 for b, 4 for c, i.e. the number of instances of each character in the array
- When I don't hardcode E into the code, but instead use a reference to my spreadsheet, b gives me 1 for a, 1 for b, 1 for c. Apparently, it only recognises the first instance.
- When I log the if-condition in countInstances I can learn two things: 1) only the first instance is considered TRUE, 2) elem is still "a" for the first four times and list is also the array as I see it, meaning the evaluation of the comparison seems off, but I don't know why.
- When I go back to the code and change "elems[i]" on the line where it says "here" in the comment to "a", e.g., the correct number of a's is returned again. This is where I conclude some strange binding is happening when the value is handed over to the sub-function.

**EDIT**

The getUnique function

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
  var u = {}, a = [];
  for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
    if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
       continue;
    }
    a.push(this[i]);
    u[this[i]] = 1;
 }
 return a;
}
```

EDIT 2:

You can find an example spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BwjwomgGRmuOA51ZSW3X62eHeWWxCuxPMXXsPICeYLw/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: I'm getting the error: *Cannot find function getUnique in object a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c.*  Where is the `getUnique()` function?

Comment: Added it in the edit. It works well and I didn't want to add too much unnecessary code - sry about that

Comment: When `E` is passed from the spreadsheet custom function, does it arrive in function `J` as an array?  You can check the data type with `Logger.log('typeof J: ' + typeof J);`  That's the only thing I can think of that might make the difference?

Comment: Both, the hardcoded and the one passed from spreadsheets, have type "Object", as I would expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This function works if you want to use it as a custom formula directly in spreadsheets ([example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12gwYCrzMzWFAkMMwUIjV7iFYN1TA4OpllcExBb94ecA/edit#gid=0)):

```
function J(E) {
  var list = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < E.length; i++) 
  {
    list.push(E[i][0]);    
  }
  var elems = list.getUnique();

  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var b = countInstances(elems[i], list); //here
  }   
  return b;
}
```